# Projeto Eclipse inicia com erro

Tags: android-eclipse, app-compat-v7

Quando crio um projeto e o `appcompat_v7` está fechado o projeto fica com erro, porém se ele está aberto não tem problema, é normal os projetos depender do `appcompat_v7`?[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, é normal. Acontece que o projeto `appcompat_v7` tem as bibliotecas que o projeto precisa importar para funcionar em versões mais antigas dos emuladores, ou melhor dizendo, emuladores emulando versões mais antigas do SO Android.

Mas é possível tirar essa dependência. Tem de olhar nos arquivos .xml para isso.

Como um adendo, altere o nome do projeto com algo específico para facilmente identificar qual appcompatv7 é de qual projeto, ou adicione o projeto appcompat para a lista de projetos relacionados do qual você irá desenvolver. Irá facilitar para fechar os projetos desnecessários/abrir os necessários.

Answer (score 3):

Sim, é preciso para suportar as versões mais antigas dos emuladores. Você pode alterar o SDK para no mínimo 14 ou superior, que não tem a dependecia do appcompat.

Answer (score 1):

**DaniloAlbergardi**,

Se o seu projeto está sendo desenvolvido utilizando da biblioteca `appcompat`, é necessário que ele esteja atribuído ao seu projeto. Pela sua imagem está faltando os `imports` dessa biblioteca.

**Para que serve?**

Foi disponibilizado essas bibliotecas como modo de suporte para dispositivos que utilizam versões antigas do `Android`, podemos ilustrar um bom exemplo disso é na forma de acesso ao SDCARD entre as versões com `ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs` que pode ser utilizado em todas as versões.

Para adicionar o appcompat ao seu projeto vá em:

```
Properties do seu projeto > Android > Add e coloque o appcompat.
```

> [Documentação oficial](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/appcompat/package-summary.html)